# Livewire emitTo and redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In component AAA's view I have a button that submits an Event to component AAA

**Component AAA View:**

```
<button wire:click="$emit('goToPage')">Go To Two</button>
```

Component AAA receives it like this:

```
protected $listeners = ['goToPage'];
```

---

I then want to fire another event that **redirects** as well as **changes a tab value** from one to two in component BBB.

That looks like this (**Still in Component AAA***):

```
    public function goToPage()
    {
      $this->emit('changeTabs', $this->tab="two")->to('Alphabet.BBB');
      $this->redirectRoute('bbb', $this->bbb->id);
    }
```

---

Over on **Component BBB** I have the following:

```
    public $tab = 'one'; //THIS IS THE DEFAULT TAB

    protected $listeners = ['changeTabs'];

    public function changeTabs()
    {
        return $this->tab="two";
        //dd(Made it here);

    }
```

---

I get redirected from page AAA to page BBB, but the `changeTabs` function is not working. The tab stays at it's default tab of one.

It never reaches the `changeTabs` function return or die dump.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form what I understand:

```
$this->redirectRoute('bbb', $this->bbb->id);
```

makes HTTP redirection, so emiting events won't make any change as you make complete redirection and after redirection there is fresh component.

I would personally instead used:

```
 return redirect()->route('bbb', ['param1'=> $this->bbb->id, 'tab' => 'two']);
```

And then use request variable in component `mount` method to decide which tab should be opened.

Of course instead of exposing tab in url you can also flash this to session to be more transparent

Comment: How you explained why it isn't working makes complete sense.
Could you explain a little more about flashing this to a session? I need to change the current default $tab variable from `$tab = 'one'` to `$tab = 'two'` As you mentioned. The new value is in my URL.

Comment: @daugaard47 You can use `session()->flash('tab', 'two');` and probably in mount method you could use something like `$this->tab = session->get('tab, 'one');` to set valid tab - see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data

Comment: Thank you. That worked great. Good Idea!